# android app execution time: knowing the thread execution and memory conception

Tags: java, android, memory-management, thread-safety, performance-testing

Hi i had developed an application in android platform. I need to know how we can able to know the thread execution time and memory conception for each thread execution.

I am interested to know about the performance optimization also.

Is there any tool available to handle this .?

From the android dev Guide i came to know something like Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (DDMS), but i dont know how to use it since am a new comer to this platform..

So Experts please help me to clarify about my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using eclipse as developement IDE. If so, you can open DDMS by click Window Menu-- Open Perspective > Other-- > DDMS . Here is link for android tutorial on how to use DDMS. [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the Eclipse Memory Analyzer from http://eclipse.org/mat/
2. Save a dump from DDMS
3. Open it in MAT
4. Analyze Memory